# Update query, works fine but not i dao class

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, dao

The same query works fine in mysql workbrench, but when i run it in program had no results and even no errors. Really dont know how to fix this.

I'm using hibernate 5.0.0 and mysql connector 5.0.5

Dao looks like that:

```
Session session = null;
    Transaction tx = null;

    try {
        session = HibernateAnnotationUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        tx = session.beginTransaction();
        String hql = "UPDATE cms_asset SET `value` = CASE application_structure_id "
                + "WHEN (select id from application_structure where `name` = ? and cms_id = ?) THEN ? "
                + "WHEN (select id from application_structure where `name` = ? and cms_id = ?) THEN ? "
                + "WHEN (select id from application_structure where `name` = ? and cms_id = ?) THEN ? "
                + "WHEN (select id from application_structure where `name` = ? and cms_id = ?) THEN ? "
                + "WHEN (select id from application_structure where `name` = ? and cms_id = ?) THEN ? "
                + "WHEN (select id from application_structure where `name` = ? and cms_id = ?) THEN ? "
                + "WHEN (select id from application_structure where `name` = ? and cms_id = ?) THEN ? "
                + "WHEN (select id from application_structure where `name` = ? and cms_id = ?) THEN ? "
                + "WHEN (select id from application_structure where `name` = ? and cms_id = ?) THEN ? "
                + "ELSE `value` END WHERE application_structure_id > 0;";
        Query query = session.createSQLQuery(hql);
        query.setParameter(0, "asd");
        ...
        query.setParameter(26, "asd2");
        Integer result = query.executeUpdate();
        tx.commit();
        if(result > 0){
            return true;
        }else {
            return false;
        }   

    } catch (Exception e) {
        try {
            tx.rollback();
        } catch (RuntimeException rbe) {
            rbe.printStackTrace();
        }
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    } finally {
        if (session != null) {
            session.close();
        }
    }
```

Comment: does it complete? does it run, even? does it throw an exception? (Just assuming that the code you left out doesn't cripple the action). Have you debugged?

Comment: It works fine, but dont have change in database. I have no stacktrace. Result in this query are number of rows in table. There are no exceptions, nothing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution to the problem is to change the engine tables from InnoDB to MyISAM, then update works fine.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I remember you've to use the [SQLQuery](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.0/javadocs/org/hibernate/SQLQuery.html) Interface to handle Native SQL Updates. E.g.

```
    SQLQuery query = session.createSQLQuery(hql);
    query.setParameter(0, "asd");
    ...
    query.setParameter(26, "asd2");
    Integer result = query.executeUpdate();
```

Otherwise you may want to use [Custom SQL Annotations](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.0/userGuide/en-US/html_single/#querysql-cud) for that. But HQL would be the best option though.